# Animate.css: sliding animations not working

Tags: jquery, css, animation, animate.css, wow.js

I'm using WoW.js with animate.css to animate some elements on [my project](http://www.bwdmedia.in/camelport/) and one of the element is just not budging. It's a span tag that say "`Learn How We Can Help You Reach Further`". On this tag `fadeInleft` and `slideInLeft` doesn't work although `bounceInRight` does work.

```
<div class="banner-content">
    <h1 class="banner-header wow flipInX" data-wow-delay="0.2s">Welcome To Simpler Logistics</h1>
    <span class="wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.4s">See How We Can </span><span class="wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.4s">Help You Reach Further</span><br>
    <button class="btn btn-trans wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.6s">Learn More <i class="fa fa-chevron-down hvr-icon-hang"></i></button>
</div>
```

Changing the `<span>` tags to `<p>` tags seems to work (but that's not a solution) so I looked for css that targets the `span` tag but there isn't any except `font-size`

```
.banner-content span{
    font-size: 2vw;
}
```

I tried commenting it out, just to check but that's not it. I tried iolating each css and js file but none of them seems to be the culprit.

Next, I updated to the latest versions of `animate.css` and `wow.min.js` but the problem is still there.

Can someone please help me debug the issue?

Comment: Please give me any suggestions you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<span>` elements are `display:inline` by default, but `<p>` elements are `display:block`.

Try using CSS to make the span elements `display:inline-block`